# Cursor gets stack with runnable select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

```
DECLARE @a uniqueidentifier, @b uniqueidentifier, @c datetime, @d numeric(15, 2) 
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Z.ID, Z.Name, Z.Date, (V1.Credit - V2.Debet) AS Money
FROM dbo.Table1 V1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 V2
ON V2.Name = V1.Name AND V2.ID = V1.ID AND V2.Date = V1.Date
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 Z
ON Z.Name = V1.Name AND Z.ID = V1.ID AND Z.Date = V1.Date
WHERE V1.Date = DATEADD(Day, Z.AllowedDays, V2.Date)  
OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @a, @b, @c, @d
    -- Get stuck here!!!
print 'My Cursor goes ahead'
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
...
```

Can someone explain why does it get stuck in my case? I can't get the reason, because standalone Select is being completed itself.

Comment: are you sure that datatypes of @ and of the selected field match? show *all* the code, the problem might be in there.

Comment: Can you please better define "get stuck"? Is it running and running, or does the query just return successfully and not do anything more?

Comment: Also how do you even read that code? White space is a beautiful thing.

Comment: I thought so, it didn't seem like this. How can I check it for sure?

Comment: @aaron-bertrand, it doesn't return `print 'My Cursor goes ahead'`

Comment: @user1464922 that still doesn't answer my question. Is the query still running, or has the query stopped running?

Comment: @aaron-bertrand, still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually step within your loop, you do this by repeating the fetch inside the loop:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @a

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Some operations

    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @a
----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
END
```

Otherwise, it's an infinite loop, constantly processing the first row.

As an aside, a cursor is very rarely the right answer; perhaps you should consider trying a set-based solution instead of a cursor. If you really need a cursor, at the very least, do this:

```
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
```

If the query is spinning and spinning, then it's probably being blocked. This could be due to the cursor options, so trying `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD` may help, but it's probably more than that. We can't guess what you're being blocked by but you can check for yourself. Stop the query, and in that window, do `SELECT @@SPID;` and note the number that is returned. Now, start the cursor query again, and open a new window. Run the following (replacing `x` with the `@@SPID` number):

```
SELECT blocking_session_id, wait_type FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
  WHERE session_id = x;
```

Now, if you get another session id in the first column, you can see what they are doing and why they are blocking you, using a similar query and a `DBCC` command:

```
SELECT status, command FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
  WHERE session_id = y;

DBCC INPUTBUFFER(y);
```

(Again, replacing `y` with the session id from the previous query.)

Comment: I know, it doesn't run the loop anyway (simply checked by prints). Please see where it gets stuck.

Comment: @user1464922 Maybe there is an error in your query. Impossible for us to tell, because you commented it out.